# How to register a company into Windows Phone store?

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-store-apps, windows-phone-store

I am fresher in Windows Phone development. I am working in a small company in India and developing an app for Windows Phone 8.

I am using Visual Studio ultimate 2013. I did complement my project with the help of IDE and emulator but I don't know that how to register a company into Windows Phone app store to sell application.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to create a Developer account and once you will be doing that you will have the choice to create an individual account or an entreprise account . Hope this will help :)